# Beep anytime evaluation finishes

Tags: evaluation, customization, sound

These days I have to do long evaluations and I would like to get back to my notebook as soon as they end. Is there a way to ask *Mathematica* to produce a sound signal anytime it ends an evaluation?

I know I could use `Beep[]` or ask *Mathematica* to say something more silly with `Speak[]`. Yet I would also have to copy and paste these commands at the end of each cell, and this may be annoying. Is there a way to have this done for any evaluation in my notebook?

Comment: `EvaluationCompletionAction`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative to `EvaluationCompletionAction` would be to adjust `$Post`. Try

```
Clear[f];
f[x___] := With[{}, Beep[]; x]
$Post=f;
```

Now `Beep` will also be evaluated once every evaluation. Use `$Post=.` to stop the beeping.

Answer (score 6):

I would use

```
$Post = (Beep[]; #) &
```